# How to define let! with mutliple objects in Rspec test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm practicing my Rails tests and right now I don't know how to solve this issue: How to define multiple objects using let! method. It returns normal array, not ActiveRecord relation. I guess that they should be both ActiveRelation relation type to be able to compare.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe PostsController do

  let!(:posts) do 
      [Post.create(title: "Title 1", body: "Body 1"), Post.create(title: "Title 2", body: "Body 2")]
  end

  describe "posts" do
    it "assigns @posts" do

      get :index
      expect(assigns(:posts)).to eq([posts])
    end
  end

end
```

After running tests:

```
PostsController
  posts
    assigns @posts (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) PostsController posts assigns @posts
     Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:posts)).to eq([posts])

       expected: [[#<Post id: 1, title: "Title 1", body: "Body 1", created_at: "2016-10-23 05:40:39", updated_at: "201...: "Title 2", body: "Body 2", created_at: "2016-10-23 05:40:39", updated_at: "2016-10-23 05:40:39">]]
            got: #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Post id: 1, title: "Title 1", body: "Body 1", created_at: "2016-10-23 05:...: "Title 2", body: "Body 2", created_at: "2016-10-23 05:40:39", updated_at: "2016-10-23 05:40:39">]>

       (compared using ==)

       Diff:
       @@ -1,3 +1,13 @@
       -[[#<Post id: 1, title: "Title 1", body: "Body 1", created_at: "2016-10-23 05:40:39", updated_at: "2016-10-23 05:40:39">,
       -  #<Post id: 2, title: "Title 2", body: "Body 2", created_at: "2016-10-23 05:40:39", updated_at: "2016-10-23 05:40:39">]]
       +[#<Post:0x000000063ef570
       +  id: 1,
       +  title: "Title 1",
       +  body: "Body 1",
       +  created_at: Sun, 23 Oct 2016 05:40:39 UTC +00:00,
       +  updated_at: Sun, 23 Oct 2016 05:40:39 UTC +00:00>,
       + #<Post:0x000000063ef228
       +  id: 2,
       +  title: "Title 2",
       +  body: "Body 2",
       +  created_at: Sun, 23 Oct 2016 05:40:39 UTC +00:00,
       +  updated_at: Sun, 23 Oct 2016 05:40:39 UTC +00:00>]

     # ./spec/controllers/posts_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.43037 seconds (files took 2.4 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/posts_controller_spec.rb:10 # PostsController posts assigns @posts
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your assignment for let!

The ActiveRecord::Relation is just because Rails is using lazy loading and is a bit misleading. The test is failing because you are sticking your array in another array, resulting in non-equality.

Change your expect call to:

```
  expect(assigns(:posts)).to eq(posts)
```

Note the removal of the square brackets.